# How can I calculate a device's daily usage time on IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to calculate the time that a person uses their iPhone on a daily basis.  I would also like to to calculate the time weekly and monthly.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (at least not without a jailbreak).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  iOS apps run in a sandboxed environment which limits what you can see about user activity.  For example, there is also no way for an app to read the SMS message history on a phone.